# How to create a floating help layout?

Tags: nativescript

I've got a {N} page and conditionally I'd like to create a floating bubble text label pointing to certain features on the page. e.g. "Press START button to blah".

Any help on how this could be done.

Preferably w/o modifying the xml page files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I released a plugin that can do what you are requesting simply install it `tns plugin add nativescript-tooltip` then you can use it as follows

TypeScript

```
import * as frame from "ui/frame";
import {ToolTip} from "nativescript-tooltip";
new ToolTip(frame.topmost().getViewById("someView"),{text:"Some Text"});
```

JavaScript

```
const frame = require("ui/frame");
const ToolTip = require("nativescript-tooltip").ToolTip;
new ToolTip(frame.topmost().getViewById("someView"),{text:"Some Text"});
```

[Plugin Repo](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-tooltip)

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for. Not sure why two peeps down voted my post - legitimate question.

Comment: Can the android styles be set in code also - like the ios style. How do you set the position of the box. I see there are some options for the arrow position. Can one say - display this tip just below this Button view etc.

Comment: "android styles be set in code" - atm no

`new ToolTip(frame.topmost().getViewById("someView"),{text:"Some Text",position:"bottom"});`

Comment: Please try to add that asap. I think with the new {N} core themes - all colors and styles are easier set from scss and css files.

Comment: Never say ASAP to someone donating his precious spare time to something you need. Thank you, every open source contributer ever.

Comment: Thank you, Eddy. @dashman you were downvoted because you failed to demonstrate any effort for research. You basically said - write my app.