# Nativescript vue tooltip use

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm using nativescript vue

I want to run this [tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-tooltip).

code like in tutorial is not working:

```
 <Button text="Get Json Data" id="tool" ref="tooltip" @tap="getData" class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"></Button>
```

I made button like this and in created trying to make it working but

```
 created() {
     let tipref = this.$refs.tooltip;
     let tippref = this.$refs.page.tooltip;
     //new ToolTip(this.nativeView.topmost().tip,{text:"Text"});
     //const tip = new ToolTip(this.nativeView.tipref,{text:"Some Text"});
     new ToolTip(tipref,{text:"Some Text"});   
},
```

still not working: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'tooltip' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeView' of undefined`

Can't figure out how to do it.

The code from the answer [How to create a floating help layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745381/how-to-create-a-floating-help-layout) is not working too.

Comment: The error is probably here: `let tippref = this.$refs.page.tooltip;`. `this.$refs.page` doesn't seem to exist. Can you try removing that line?

Comment: yes but class of tooltip looks like this `export declare class ToolTip {
    private builder;
    private tip;
    constructor(view: any, config: ToolTipConfig);
    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
    static getResource(type: any, name: any): any;
}` and in the conctructor ineed to pass view, and do not know what to pass here that what are these let tippref variables trying to achieve pass view

Comment: so what? `this.$refs.page` doesn't exist so the function crashes in that line. You are not using the var `tippref` anyways. Remove that line, please.

Comment: also, try changing from `created` to `mounted`. `created` may execute before the template is ready.

Comment: like this?    `mounted(){
         var tipref = this.$refs.tooltip;
         //new ToolTip(this.nativeView.tipref,{text:"Some Text"});  // not working
         //new ToolTip(tipref,{text:"Some Text"});  // not working
     
    },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the NativeScript View via ref, you should do `this.$refs.tooltip.nativeView`. Also wait for the loaded event of the element to make sure it's ready to use.

```
<template>
  <Page class="page">
    <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar"/>
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout class="home-panel">
        <Button
          text="Get Json Data"
          ref="tooltip"
          class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"
          @loaded="onLoaded"
        ></Button>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    onLoaded: function(args) {
      const ToolTip = require("nativescript-tooltip").ToolTip;
      const tip = new ToolTip(args.object, {
        text: "Some Text",
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        textColor: "black"
      });
      tip.show();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: its working .I had error something like "bulder" and had to delete android device and restart and working